# process.Start() is throwing exception "The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: c#, .net

`process.Start()` is throwing exception

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll
>
> The system cannot find the file specified

C# Code is

```
Process process = new Process() 
process.StartInfo.FileName= "..."; 
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "directory of exe file";
process.StartInfo.Arguments= "…";
process.Start();
```

It is working fine on 5 machines but on 1 machine it is not working.  If I give complete path in file name then it works.  i.e:

```
process.StartInfo.FileName= "complete path of exe.";
```

But I do not want to give complete path, as I have already given Working Directory and It is working on other machines.

Could you please give me the reason why it is not working if you know?

Comment: Have you tried... checking if File.Exists() ? :>

Comment: How would we reproduce this?

Comment: yes, file exists. the same code is working for other machines. As I have mentioned in my question that it is working fine on 5 other machines.

Comment: my machine is 64 bit. it is working on other 64 bit machines all are laptop and windows OS 8.

Comment: Is the path you are passing relative or absolute? We need an example of the path format

Comment: A lot changes between machines. OS, service pack, installed files. Don't assume that it _will work_ on evidence that it _has worked_.

Comment: is working directory for the above code is same as the exe ?

Comment: Perhaps related to the PATH environment variable?

Comment: Does the process which runs the application have access rights to the file?